# Are singletons closed in the extended real line?

Tags: general-topology

Considering the extended real line $\mathbb{\overline{R}}=[-\infty ,+\infty]$ and the topology $\tau$ generated by the family

$\cal{U}=$$\{U(x,k):x\in[-\infty,+\infty],k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $$U(x,k)=\begin{cases} (x-k^{-1},x+k^{-1})& \text{when}& x\in\mathbb{R} \\ [-\infty,-k)&\text{when} &x=-\infty\\ (k,+\infty] & \text{when}&x=+\infty \end{cases}$$

I would like to determine whether the singletons $\{a\}$ are closed $\forall a \in \mathbb{\overline{R}}$

Since the complement of $\{a\}$ is $[-\infty,a)\cup(a,+\infty]$, I concern myself with only showing that both $[-\infty,a)$ and $(a,+\infty]$ are open.
To do this, I know no other way except to write them in terms of members of $\cal{U}$ since $\cal{U} \subseteq \tau$, I would guarantee that they are elements of the topology.

How can I do this? More importantly, am I on the right track?

I have read numerous others posts on the issue but all seem to treat $[-\infty,a)$ and $(a,+\infty]$ as by definition to be open. Since this topology is rather finnicky, I need to more concretely show this.

Comment: Hint: consider $U(a+c,1)$ for $c\geq 1$...

Comment: Well that's $(a+c-1,a+c+1)$ no?
The countable union for $c \in \mathbb{N}$ is $(a+c-1,+\infty)$?

Comment: Actually, I made a small mistake,the union over $c\in \mathbb{N}$ should be $(a,+\infty)$ but still the point $\{+\infty\}$ is missing

Comment: You can take union with one more set.

Comment: @Wojowu 
$U(+\infty,a)$? Ah I see!
For the other set then, I'll consider $U(a-c,1)$ which are intervals of the form $(a-c-1,a-c+1)$ and their union over $c \in \mathbb{N}$ is $(-\infty,a)$ and in that case I'll take it union with $U(-\infty,a)$!

Comment: @Wojowu But in the case where you consider $a=+-\infty$ wouldn't that break the argument?

Comment: The argument does indeed break for $a=\pm\infty$. These have to be dealt with using separate arguments. $a=-\infty$ is easy, and for $a=\infty$ you just have to realize $(a,\infty]$ is empty, and empty set is always open.

Comment: @Wojowu
I am aware that the empty set is open by definition of topology but now I'm left to prove that $(-\infty,+\infty]$ and $[-\infty,+\infty)$ are open...

Comment: @Wojowu
Would this work? Or is there a simpler argument that you were referring to?

1) $$[-\infty,+\infty)=U(-\infty,1)\cup (\cup_{c \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0,-1\}}U(c,1))$$
2) $$(-\infty,+\infty]=U(+\infty,1)\cup (\cup_{c \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0,-1\}}U(-c,1))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x\in \{a\}^c$. We will see $x$ is an interior element of $\{a\}^c$ and so see $\{a\}^c$ is open.

If $x<a$ then $0<a-x$. By using Archimedian Theory there is a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0<k^{-1}<a-x$. Then $x-k^{-1}<x<x+k^{-1}<a$ so $(x-k^{-1},x+k^{-1})\subset \{a\}^c$. Therefore $\{a\}^c$ is open.

If $a<x$. By the same argument above we have a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0<k^{-1}<x-a$ . So $a+k^{-1}<x$. Then $a<x-k^{-1}<x<x+k^{-1}$ so $(x-k^{-1},x+k^{-1})\subset \{a\}^c$. Therefore $\{a\}^c$ is open.

Therefore $\{a\}^c$ is open and $\{a\}$ is closed.

Comment: Absolutely amazingly beautiful and slick proof!

Comment: So for all a in (-oo,oo), {a} is closed.  What if a = oo or a = -oo?

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks. @ William Elliot It is obvious. When $a=\infty$ or $a=-\infty$, respectively just use first or second "if" above.

Comment: @WilliamElliot
By the algebraic properties of $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, nothing is violated in the proof. So in actuality it holds $\forall a \in [-\infty,+\infty]$

Comment: @Malcolm The rules for algebra, +, -, * and ÷ don't hold for oo and -oo.

Comment: @WilliamElliot the proof includes not only real numbers but also the infinities.

Comment: @WilliamElliot
For the standard real line, this is true. 
But in the extended real line, where $\{+\infty\},\{-\infty\}$ are points added to $\mathbb{R}$, you necessarily must define some form of arithmetic operations to those points.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations